# Adding images in a div within Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

i am making an interactive website in which a kitchen will be displayed. the cabinets of that kitchen need to be interactive ( opening a cabinet and closing it ).

i can already open all the cabinets so that is not the problem.
here comes the real problem:

when those cabinets open, 2/3 products per cabinet need to appear.
problem is, i do not know how to insert those images through javascript. i want them only to show up when a cabinet opens.

here is my javascript code for 1 of the cabinets:

```
    function pictureChange1() {
       document.getElementById('noob').src="kastjeopen1boven.jpg";

    }
```

its small but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .css() option in Jquery to hide/show the part of Images when the cabinet is opened. It can be done like this:

- When Cabinet is opened, show only 2/3 of the image by using  .css('padding','x');
- Also When the cabinet is closed hide the images.